# Ad recommender system in python

Tags: python, recommendation-engine, collaborative-filtering

I have tried to use following lib to create simple ad recommender system:
http://surpriselib.com/
Surprise lib stricts data folds structure:

> Such a file is assumed to specify only one rating per line, and each
>   line needs to respect the following structure:
>
> user ; item ; rating ; [timestamp]

I work with a simple structure without *rating*:

```
user_id ad_id
```

It defines user clicks on ads. I need some kind of collaborative filter to suggest proper ads to user. Should I use other library for doing this or are there other ways for creating ad recommender?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For building an Recommender system you can use the Graphlab Create Library

Also it includes the sample application with recommender application.

> https://github.com/turi-code/sample-movie-recommender

For details refer:

> https://turi.com/learn/userguide/recommender/introduction.html